# PermissionError trying to use subprocess to call other program in Python

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to make a interface, so I just tried to use `subprocess` module to call my program:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('/Users/TsuAngChou/MasterProject/Practice/try_test/TEST5.py')
```

I tried to run it, but there was an **error**:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied.
```

What's going on in my code?

Comment: Is the error from the `subprocess.call()` or from running `TEST5.py`?

Comment: I think it is from subprocess.call()

Answer (score 0):

You don't have permission to execute the script - probably because the script file does not have executable permission set for it.

Perhaps also it is missing the `#!/usr/bin/env python` (aka "shebang") at the top of `test.py`.

Try using `chmod` to set executable on the file:

```
$ chmod +x test.py
```

and add the shebang at the top. Then makes sure that you can execute it from the command line:

```
$ ./test.py
```

---

Also, it is often possible, and better, to *import* the code into your script and call the functions within it it.